# Using custom functions on all pages in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I have a function

```
public function add($value1,$value2){

$a = $value1;
$b = $value2;
$c = $a + $b;

return $c;

}
```

In order to  call this function i would use `add(1,2)`

The problem is :
if i want to be able to use this function on any view page in laravel, where do i place it and how do i call it ?

I have tried using it on page and it works fine, i just need a global solution.

```
public function add($value1,$value2){

    $a = $value1;
    $b = $value2;
    $c = $a + $b;

    return $c;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a helper file.
So create a helper.php file in app. `app/helper.php`

then in composer.json add the following under autoload:

```
"files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ],
```

Then dump composer

```
composer dump-auto
```

Now you can call your function.